# Is the Windows Azure Web Deployment Accelerator production deployment capable?

Tags: azure-storage, webdeploy

The documentation for the Windows Azure Web Deploy functionality states that it's basically only for test development principally because any changes made do not persist should an instance be recycled.

I recently had the experience of a using remote desktop to update some files in an Azure run (test) website thinking that since i was actually updating the website itself and not say the desktop, that it would persist. Turns out that no that's incorrect thinking, when the role was recycled all the changes i had made via remote desktop were wiped back to the original 20min package upload. I'm glad i made that mistake because it made so many other things crystal clear.

So i looked for ways around this and read about web deploy but if i was to face the same situation as above the changes would still be wiped.

Now there is the [Web Deployment Accelerator](http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deploying%20the%20Web%20Host%20to%20Windows%20Azure) and from what i can gather this will persist in a production site, across all forms of instance recycling etc because all the changes are now being stored on Azure storage.

Is my understanding correct? 
Can Windows Azure Web Deploy Accelerator be used (in a sense) like an FTP client to a "regular" IIS website? Are there conditions under which changes I make to say a site with a shopping cart will be lost because I used this technology as my Azure "FTP client".*

(Yes i know it's not "actually" FTP) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes you make with this accelerator will persist and never get wiped out by role instances rebooting, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I watched the cloud cover video number 51. I know you said it but i thought it was so one time before and got bitten, and so i needed to be absolutely, over the top, certain. Coming off the trial so i really want to start using some of these multi domain features "for real" and i dont want any nasty surprises re: shopping carts etc. This accelerator combined with Azure makes the small ISV | Webhosters life so much easier. It's like an early Xmas present. I am genuinely very excited about this piece of technology. Awesome stuff thanks.